# How to properly perform batch updates on an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, batch-updates

For `UITableView`s, the order of insertion, deletion and move operations does not matter inside an update block because they are not performed until `-endAnimations` is called, and then, they are performed as a **[batch update](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9)**.

Let's say I have 3 arrays:
 - deletions (just an index)
 - insertions (index + object)
 - moves (two indices)

How would I properly apply this 'delta' to an existing array, just like `UITableView` would in its batch updates?

Comment: FYI, Apple introduced performBatchUpdates:completion: On UITableview from iOS11, give a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that you keep a dictionary (or array, actually) interpreting the index numbers in terms of what happens during each change. Originally 0 means 0, 1 means 1, and so on. But if you delete item 1, let's say, then 2 means 1, 3 means 2, etc. - everything above it has to be shoved down, so that if you ask to interchange item 2 with something we can still find the object you meant by "2" at the time you said it. Similarly if you then insert something at item 2, everything above it has to be shoved up.

Now you can do the deletions, then the insertions, then the moves. Note that you have to do the deletions *in reverse sorted index order* (or use an index set so you can delete them all at once) and the insertions *in normal sorted order*.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about. Can you maybe provide a little sample code on how to do the index mapping?